# Bending invariants in higher dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry

The determinant of the Gauss map of an embedded surface in 3 space is a bending invariant of the surface.

What about the determinant of the Gauss map for hypersurfaces of n space?

How does one obtain all of the bending invariants of the hypersurface from the Gauss map?

Comment: What do you mean by determinant of the Gauss map?  The derivative has a determinant, but this is just the curvature.

Comment: Yes, the determinant of the differential of the Gauss map. I know it's the Gauss curvature for a surface. I am asking about the same questions for hypersurfaces in higher dimensional Euclidean space e.g. 5 manifolds in 6 space.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are interested in is the product of the principal curvatures for hypersurfaces in Euclidean $n$-space for $n\geq 4$.  This quantity is not a Riemannian invariant, i.e. it is not preserved by isometries.  When you say that you want to obtain all the bending invariants from the Gauss map, do you mean sectional curvature?  If so, in each two-dimensional direction determined by a pair of principal directions, the sectional curvature will be the product of the two principal curvatures, just as for Gaussian curvature.